# Which Antivirus program is best for Ubuntu?

Tags: security, antivirus

I have a option Clamav but it lacks real time protection. I want a real time protection in my system. What about Comodo and Sophos?

Comment: I don't get why this is downvoted. It's a valid question, although the answer wil probably not be what the OP expected.

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Comment: I can see this will soon be closed and it is unfortunate antivirus on Ubuntu turn into flame wars. Although for the most part linux security is not the same as windows security although there are a few user cases where it makes sense to use antivirus where you are sharing files with Windows such as file servers or mail servers

Answer (score 4):

All virus scanners are crap and not worth your time. There is no "best"; only "the least worse": All of them are using Windows based rules to scan for problems on Linux files. That never works. And never will work. If you want to scan files before passing them to Windows: pick any. You don't need real time protection for those since you are scanning files before executing them on Windows.

Common sense is more important on Linux (to protect from any harm not just virusses):

1. don't use off line mail.
2. download from trusted sources and only install software where you trust the source.
3. have a good admin password (and do not store it).
4. make sure users that are on your system are trusted or use a guest account.
5. don't run code you are offered unless you understand what it does.
6. make backups of important files.

Abide those rules and your system is sufficiently protected without the need to impede the performance of your system. Don't believe the Windows way is the only, nor that it is the correct way of maintaining a computer that is used to go on-line.

If you want to detect problems with your Linux system you could install rootkit detectors made for Linux. You will need these two (1 permanently running and the 2nd to confirm the results the 1st shows (if 2 detect the same problem it is worth investigating)):

- Chkrootkit is a classic rootkit scanner. It checks your server for suspicious rootkit processes and checks for a list of known rootkit files.

  ```
  sudo apt install chkrootkit
  ```
- Lynis (formerly rkhunter) is a security auditing tool for Linux and BSD based systems. It performs a detailed auditing of many security aspects and configurations of your system. Download the latest Lynis sources from https://cisofy.com/download/lynis/:

  ```
  cd /tmp
  wget https://cisofy.com/files/lynis-2.6.1.tar.gz
  tar xvfz lynis-2.6.1.tar.gz
  mv lynis /usr/local/
  ln -s /usr/local/lynis/lynis /usr/local/bin/lynis
  ```

But these are overkill if you run a desktop. Keeping your system upgraded and using Ubuntu active versions, having a good admin password and not install software from unknown sources is more than enough. We have yet to see all of our desktops compromised in a way Microsoft allows to happen.

Comment: "don't use off line mail"? How does that protect you from anything?

Comment: @SebastianStark off line mail can import attachments onto your system. That means the a file could be executed introducing an attack vector. You home is not safe from deleting or from locking your personal files if the owner of the executed file is your user name (it does not require admin access to remove content from /home/$USER).

Comment: I see what you mean now, although I think if you're being selective enough of which folders/messages to store offline it is not more dangerous than online mail.

Comment: Sure. But you are one exploited bug in your mailclient away from it being executed behind the scenes. online mail is the ultimate sandbox:  that introduces you executing the attachment you downloaded. And it should set off at least an alarm bell then ;-)

Comment: Just to be sure: with online mail you mean using IMAP without local caching? Because if you mean browser based email I would not agree that this is less dangerous. Thinking of browser bugs, XSS, phishing attacks, danger from ads.

Comment: Google mail for instance. That and the browser sandboxing is the better protection. Google actively removes attachments that contain suspicious content for instance and does not allow you to include executables.

Comment: I do not agree that suggesting to hand over all your data to a third party company  is a good advice. But I agree that using a (good) web based email client could be a useful security measure.

Comment: This is not possible for some basic users as they have little knowledge to maintain Linux distros. Also, the linux platform is the biggest, so is the virus and malware threats. As to my knowledge, there is only one open source antivirus built for linux platform. Why this? Nobody cares about that threat.

Comment: There are valid user cases for antivirus on Linux. Mail servers, file servers, and perhaps scanning removable devices. I agree they are not great due to false positives more than false negatives. To be honest I have not seen a false negative on Linux antivirus scanners.

Comment: Only for scanning windows related problems. Not linux. In 25 years I have yet to see a  Linux system with a virus.

Comment: Slapper? Devnull? Xor DDOS? Linux.Encoder.1? Half of all zombies in botnets are Linux fanboys who think they're magically immune to viruses. People that follow the instructions in the answer don't get viruses on Windows either. Antiviruses are for the 99% of the population that screws up every now and then. And most people that are asking n00b questions on a Linux forum are people that are in a multi-OS environment so if nothing else they'll benefit from scanning files to/from their Windows box.

Comment: "People that follow the instructions in the answer don't get viruses on Windows either." Correct. 1 difference: we are taught to follow these. 2. any of these you listed require access to the system and access to the admin password. Besides that: you wont find these using clamav on Linux since you will be wasting your time wading through 1000s of false notices. You need at least two independent linux based rootkit detectors. "so if nothing else they'll benefit from scanning files to/from their Windows box" ONLY if they use Linux as a GATEWAY. Not when both are directly connected to the web,

Comment: There @TBridges42 added rootkit scanners into it. I do insist though that these are serious overkill for a desktop user. If you run a webserver these are mandatory (or better yet get a paid rootkit detector like ISPProtect https://ispprotect.com/ ).